# URI encoded hashtag within url automatically decoded through PushState

Tags: jquery, urlencode, history.js

I am trying to push a URL with a url encoded hashtag (I'm building a Twitter client). History.js apparently considers URI encoded hashtags (%23) as hash parameters in the URL so automatically URL decodes them, hence triggers no state change with such links.

For example the url /first/%23second gets converted as /first/#second

What could I do without messing up the whole plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you host the History.js file locally, look inside for a function on the m object called "unescapeString" (or just Ctrl+F to "m.unescapeString".

You can then change it to this:

```
m.unescapeString=function(b){
    var c=b,d;

    if(!history.pushState){  //Adding this check.
        for(;;) {
            d = a.unescape(c);

            if (d===c) 
                break;

            c = d;
        }
    }
return c
}
```

This will basically fix your issue. (I believe that this method is used for supporting browsers that don't support history.pushState)